# Selenium ChromeDriver: Error on Compiling - The driver executable does not exist

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

```
public static void testGoogleSearch() 
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\TEST\\Documents\\chromedriver_win32.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(150, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        //driver.quit();
    }
```

Cant really make it work, its my first time using chromedriver so I'm having a hard time doing the set up, please someone help me. Been reading some threads relating to this but still cant find a solution.
Thanks in advance!

Already installed chrome and chroemdriver.

Comment: Can you specify the error you are getting?

Comment: Put your code inside the {} tag to display code properly

Comment: Hi, thanks for the responses, solved it! Just added chromedriver.exe :)

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\TEST\\Documents\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");

Answer (score 0):

use below code

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","G:\\ravik\\Ravi-Training\\Selenium\\Drivers\\cd\\chromedriver.exe");
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    ChromeDriver d1 = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```